# How would you display users engaging in the same app activity with the same first name and last name?

Tags: users, names, displays

(Super edge case?). I'm making an app that will pit users against each other. How would I display 2 people with exactly the same name against each other. If they have avatars, it would be easy (just show their avatar to distinguish) but let's say for the sake of discussion that they don't.

Something like John Doe vs John Doe.

Comment: Does the users have middle name(s)?

Comment: Use nicknames/usernames instead?

Comment: Where is this being displayed? what have you tried / thought of so far?

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho, yes, they have nicknames (and unique emails), but they are guest accounts imported from a phone book. So if they are imported, they might now have these values set at the start of the activity.

Comment: @AndrewMartin honestly we're just displaying the same names, think "John vs John". We're using it in the context of something that is like a bowling score sheet.

Comment: @locationunknown No middle names yet.

Answer (score 5):

I would do two things simultaneously:

- add "you" to username (e.g. "**John Doe (you)**") - which would allow them to easily know which one is them - however not having any distinction between the other ones.
- use avatars.

Then, as some of Users may have avatars unset, I would assign them something like Google does in Google docs, differentiating just colour and shape, not username:

[image]

The only thing I would change would be displaying actual name. They would get used to the temporary avatars with time.

Comment: +1 Given the nature and detail of the question, this is a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't take a great deal of thought to start with creating a common pattern. It the current player's name is always in the same place on the screen then it doesn't matter if their opponent has the same name because it won't appear in the current player space: Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwzQel.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Alternatively, you could try just showing the opponents name, showing the names in different colours, different sizes... there are lots of ways to do this without needing to bend your brain too much.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really happy with this answer - the question is really broad and the OP has not really demonstrated the specifics of the problem they're trying to deal with so this answer is really wooly.